# Check status of payment with paypal having only info of payment gived from user in a secont moment

Tags: php, paypal

How i can get the status of a payment with paypal having only:

```
1) Transaction id;
2) email;
3) date of transaction;
4) import.
```

These information are gived in a second moment and NOT at moment of payment from user which done payment.
Shortly, need something so:

```
if (something($email, $trasaction_id, $date, $import) == "COMPLETED") {
  echo "Payment completed successful!";
} else {
  echo "Payment not completed";
}
```

I have searched here and found something but nothing helped me about this specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sending the transaction id to the api function [`GetTransactionDetails`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/).

> - None — No status
> - Canceled-Reversal — A reversal has been canceled, for example, when you win a dispute and the funds for the reversal have been returned to
>     you.
> - Completed — The payment has been completed, and the funds have been added successfully to your account balance.
> - Denied — You denied the payment. This happens only if the payment was previously pending because of possible reasons described for the
>     PendingReason element.
> - Expired — The authorization period for this payment has been reached.
> - Failed — The payment has failed. This happens only if the payment was made from your buyer's bank account.
> - In-Progress — The transaction has not terminated, for example, an authorization may be awaiting completion.
> - Partially-Refunded — The payment has been partially refunded.
> - Pending — The payment is pending. See the PendingReason field for more information.
> - Refunded — You refunded the payment.
> - Reversed — A payment was reversed due to a chargeback or other type of reversal.   The funds have been removed from your account balance
>     and returned to the buyer.
> - The reason for the reversal is specified in the ReasonCode element.
> - Processed — A payment has been accepted.
> - Voided — An authorization for this transaction has been voided.

Comment: Thanks, have a link where i can look an example of how use it better? From your link i get only a list of parameter. Just for understand better how implement it.

Comment: Well you have to go read the api docs then. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/

Comment: I have read both links, but not help me much. Ok with it i get detail about the transaction but how i can check which that transaction id done from people with gived email? I need to validate the transaction id if is completed and if done from user with gived email used for payment.